# Почему не синхронизируются объекты?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Network Transform и Network Identity на префабе bullet есть. Но у каждого игрока спавнятся свои префабы, которые не отображаются на экране соперника.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    bool ready = true;
    public Transform firePoint;
    public bool shot;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) || shot)
        {
            if (ready)
            {
                Shoot();
            }
            else
            {
                // пустой звук
            }
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        ready = false;
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        LeanTween.delayedCall(6f, () => { ready = true; });
    }
}
```

Comment: здесь нет сетевого кода...

Comment: Почему у меня без всякого кода тогда другие модели синхронизируются?

Comment: У меня нет никакого сетевого кода, я просто добавил Network Manager & Network Manager HUD на пустой объект Networking, и в Spawn Info -> Player Prefab, указал  префаб модели при заходе игрока на сервер (на префабе есть Network Transform, Network Identity). Все синхронизируется, никаких скриптов.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/net-NetworkInstantiate.html

Comment: Ничего не поменялось